# How do I connect a Laravel app to a Lumen api service together?

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

We are working on a project that allows users to register and login from a laravel app to an api service built with lumen, but the issue we are having is how do we authenticate the laravel app the same time, after a successful authentication from lumen.

[image]

Comment: You can use Passport for that, please check Laravel official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The landing page, (even if it's on the main domain) should submit to the dashboard domain and authenticate user using JWT (Json Web Token) or laravel passport (which uses it too)
[image: basic s]

Let the dashboard send the login request. The api should provide a token of authentification which the dashboard keeps in session for use in further requests.

The dashboard should only communicate with the API and not directly with the database. It will help with your project's future modification.

Comment: can't we use the laravel Auth::login() for the main domain (Landing Page) then authenticate the api separately.

Comment: but then you need to have two model of user on two seperate installation, using the same database + two authentification systems using the same data (credentials). When you modify one, you'll need to update the other in the exact way.